# One method for two UIButtons

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton

This rewind method is for rewind button as well as for play button.

```
-(void)rewind:(id)sender
{
    [timer invalidate]; 
    audioPlayer.currentTime = 0;

    MainViewController *viewController = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
    viewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
    [self.view addSubview:viewController.view];
    [self.view addSubview:toolbar];
    [viewController release];

    if([audioPlayer isPlaying])
    {
        [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Play Icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [audioPlayer pause];
        [self pauseTimer];
        [self pauseLayer:self.view.layer];  
    }else{
        [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [audioPlayer play];
        [self resumeTimer];
        [self resumeLayer:self.view.layer];
        if(isFirstTime == YES)
        {
            self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:11.0
                                                          target:self
                                                        selector:@selector(displayviewsAction:)
                                                        userInfo:nil
                                                         repeats:NO];
            isFirstTime = NO;
        }
    } 
}
```

Now in this method sender is rewind button and toggling of play/pause is happening on rewind button whereas i want this toggling on play button rather then sender which is rewind button. So i tried giving the name of the actual button on which i want toggling to happen and i defined that button as play button in my code and whose action method i have added in this rewind method.

That's how defined the play button

```
//Add Play Button
UIButton *playButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[playButton addTarget:self action:@selector(playpauseAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
playButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30);
[playButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Play Icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[playButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
UIBarButtonItem *play = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:playButton];
```

and this is the method of play button which i added in the rewind button

```
-(void)playpauseAction:(id)sender 
{    
    if([audioPlayer isPlaying])
    {
        [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Play Icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [audioPlayer pause];
        [self pauseTimer];
        [self pauseLayer:self.view.layer];
    }
    else
    {
        [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [audioPlayer play];
        [self resumeTimer];
        [self resumeLayer:self.view.layer];

        if(isFirstTime == YES)
        {
            self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:11.0
                                                          target:self
                                                        selector:@selector(displayviewsAction:)
                                                        userInfo:nil
                                                         repeats:NO];
            isFirstTime = NO;
        }
    }
}
```

now problem i m facing at this time is that when i m clicking the rewind button toggling should happen on play button than rewind button.

But to fix this problem i simply replaced sender with playButton in the rewind method like this

```
[playButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Play Icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

but then i get warning message in red that use of undeclared identifier playButton.

How can i tell rewind method to do toggling on playButton rather then on rewind button.

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your "undeclared identifier playButton" is telling you that you don't have an instance variable playButton.

It is probably only visible in the method where you created it, but you need to save it into an iVar to be able to access it from the other method.

Comment: defined property for playButton and synthesize playButton but now at the init of playButton it says hides instance variable and to remove that had to rename init playButton to playpauseButton. still problem is same how method will recognize which button i m talking about

Comment: @synthesize playButton = _playButton; Or give them both a different name.

Comment: all warning messages are gone but now when clicking on rewind button then play button is not toggling to pause.

Comment: All your left with now is a logic problem - you might need to simplify and pull your code out into multiple methods to simplify, instead of trying to do it all in one method. What is audioPlayer? Is it a MPMoviePlayerController or a MPMusicPlayerController by any chance? This both have notifications that you can listen to which give you the playback state. You could use these playback notifications to change your UI (i.e the play pause button) It might simplify your logic. Then you can use your actions methods just to trigger the play/pause.